# Couldn't match expected type - Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, floating-point, int

I'm new to Haskell and still can't quite figure out these type issues.  I'm getting errors for the following function:

```
computeTriUp :: Point -> Float -> [Point]
computeTriUp center r = [(x + r*cos(pi/2.0), y+r*sin(pi/2.0)), (x+r*cos(5.0*pi/4.0),       y+r*sin(5.0*pi/4.0)), (x+r*cos(7.0*pi/4.0), y+r*sin(7.0*pi/4.0))]
    where x = fst center
          y = snd center
```

My error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Float'
In the first argument of `(*)', namely `r'
In the second argument of `(+)', namely `r * cos (pi / 2.0)'
In the expression: x + r * cos (pi / 2.0)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the definition of `Point`?

Comment: Also, you're better off with an explicit pattern match on `(x,y)`, unless you intend to replace the definition of `Point` later and doing this will minimise code change...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Point is a pair of Ints, you probably want to change the definitions of x and y to convert them to Floats...

```
x = fromIntegral $ fst centre
```

Comment: This is going to run into problems as the result is also declared to be a list of `Point`s. I think the better option is to make `Point` contain `Float`s instead...